# Does the GEE estimation and mixed models handle data missing inside a series?

Tags: mixed-model, missing-data, generalized-estimating-equations

I'm wondering, if either GEE or mixed models can handle all the 4 cases of missing data:

T0 T1 T2 T3
m  +  +  + (missing at t0, late entry)

- m  +  + (missing inside a series, here at t1)
- - - m (missing at the end, here t3)
      m  m  +  m (missing at any place)

I know the geepack in R handles the "waves" argument. Does it mean, thet, if patient X has observation only at t3, the "wave" should have "4" for this patient and it suffices?